# How to find arithmetic operator and assign it and its index to globally accessible variable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, for-loop, if-statement

I'm a web developer newbie and am trying to build a calculator in React as a practice project.

In order to do this, I need the user-selected arithmetic operations ("+", "/", "-" or "X") to be carried out when the user clicks "=".

I push all characters of the buttons that the user clicks to an array, including arithmetic operators.

So for example if the user clicks "3", then "+", then "6", the state array (called "numberList") is [3, "+", 6]. The problem I'm having is with identifying the index of the arithmetic operator. I have tried various combinations of loops, if statements, and array methods. This is my latest attempt:

```
      for (let i = 0; i < numberList.length; i++) {
        switch (numberList[i]) {
          case "+":
            operator = "+";
            operatorIndex = i;
            break;
          case "/":
            operator = "/";
            operatorIndex = i;
            break;
          case "-":
            operator = "-";
            operatorIndex = i;
            break;
          case "X":
            operator = "X";
            operatorIndex = i;
            break;
          default:
            return "ERR";
        }
      }
      //Find operators and their index in numberList
      console.log(numberList, operator, operatorIndex);
```

But when I run this the "ERR" default is returned even when there is a matching arithmetic operator in the numberList array.

Why doesn't the code continue after "operator" and "operatorIndex" have been assigned the values of the operator and its index?

Thanks, David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always 'ERR' is returned because the first element of the array is a number and on you switch statement you use a `return` instead of `break`.

if you want an easy solution you can use the following code:

```
const numberList = [3, "+", 6];
const result = eval(numberList.join('').replaceAll('X', '*'));
console.log(result); // 7
```

note: eval may bring some security issues so it shouldn't be used. More info on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

Comment: Hi. I am indeed trying to avoid eval. But the tip about avoiding return in the default switch case and replacing it with a "break;" solved my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since your array `numberList` can contain numbers and arithimetic operation symbols, this code will always go in `default` block if you have any number in you array, since in `switch` statement you don't have branches for handling numbers. If your array `numberList`is for example like this `numberList=[3, "+", 6]` then for numbers `3` and `6` it will go in `defuault`block although you have a match for operator "+".
Try to pass `numberList` like this `var numberList = ["+","-"];` and you will see that there will be no error. By the way, your code will always throw an error like `Illegal return statement` since return-statements are only allowed inside of functions.